# 5 buttons accessing same startup script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a scenario in which 5 buttons else two or more same controls need to access the same startupscript (ASP.NET). Is it possible?? If so give me a details code snippet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the same startupscript"? Your question is very unclear. Please explain what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, have all the buttons submit the same form.

```
<form action='yourScript.asp' action='post'>
  <button name='b1'>1</button>
  <button name='b2'>2</button>
</form>
```

Then check in your script which of the buttons was sent.